# Running Appium script through remote url connection instead of localhost

Tags: python, android, selenium-webdriver, appium, remote-access

I have a windows virtual machine in which Appium installed and there's a physical device connected to it.

In the virtual machine the code below is working fine which get the date from the mobile connected :

```
from appium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection import RemoteConnection

dc={
"platformName": "Android",
"appium:deviceName": "Android Emulator",
}
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub", dc)
print(driver.get_device_time())
```

If I want to run the same code in my machine through that virtual machine , according to that reference :  https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/100038/appium.webdriver.Remote

I should be replacing the localhost with the ip address , so the code should be as the following :

```
from appium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection import RemoteConnection

dc={
"platformName": "Android",
"appium:deviceName": "Android Emulator",
}
print(dc)
# Creating the Driver by passing Desired Capabilities.
driver = webdriver.Remote(RemoteConnection("http://10.237.93.136:4723/wd/hub",resolve_ip=False),dc)

print(driver.get_device_time())
```

But it's causes the following error :

[image]

Is my approach right or not applicable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `RemoteConnection` method, the localhost is also a valid url/ip address just like the remote ip so just use `webdriver.Remote("http://10.237.93.136:4723/wd/hub", dc)`

Also make sure the ports are open and server is accessible.